# How to get variable to move with loop function excel?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a loop which moves down rows and then moves over columns. It compares Column A,B,C with D,E,F for any differences, if there are it copies it to a new sheet.

The loop works with moving across columns as the finalrow variable is reached but I am having difficulty setting up the rngSearch variable to move with the loop,

```
Sub finddata()

Dim s As Worksheet
Dim uniqueId As String
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim finalcolumn As Long
'Dim rngSearchOne As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

uniqueId = Sheets("Data").Range("B2").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Data").Range("G100000").End(xlUp).Row
finalcolumn = Sheets("Data").Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column

Set s = Sheets("Data")
Set rngSearch = s.Range(s.Cells(2, 5), s.Cells(finalrow, 5))
Set rngSearchOne = s.Range(s.Cells(i, j), s.Cells(finalrow, finalcolumn))


For j = 1 To finalcolumn Step 6
    For i = 2 To finalrow
        uniqueId = s.Cells(i, 2 + j - 1).Value
        Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=uniqueId, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If rngFound Is Nothing Then
                s.Range(Cells(i, 1 + j - 1), Cells(i, 6 + j - 1)).Copy
                Sheets("DataValidation").Range("A1048575").End(xlUp). _
                               offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            End If
    Next i
Next j


MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` at top of your module and try to compile. (You should **NEVER** work without `Option Explicit` )

Comment: Hey @PatrickHonorez I do have it at the top just copied it from Sub().

Answer (score 0):

I think your rngSeachOne is declared as the rngSearch should, but put that inside loop.

```
Set rngSearch = s.Range(s.Cells(i, j), s.Cells(i, j+5))
```

If I think good that loops should look like:

```
Set s = thisworkbook.Sheets("Data")
With s
    For j = 1 To finalcolumn Step 6
        For i = 2 To finalrow
            uniqueId = .Cells(i, 2 + j - 1).Value

            Set rngSearch = .Range(.Cells(i, j), .Cells(i, j+5))

            Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=uniqueId, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If rngFound Is Nothing Then
                    .Range(.Cells(i, 1 + j - 1), .Cells(i, 6 + j - 1)).Copy
                    Sheets("DataValidation").Range("A1048575").End(xlUp). _
                                   offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                End If
        Next i
    Next j
End with
```

Comment: It just provides the MsgBox of 'Done' if I put the rngSearch inside the loop

Comment: rngSearch is moving with the loop. Msgbox is popping up because code ends his work. How can I help You? What is wrong with code? What is not working?

Comment: Its not copying any of the cells across into the other sheet if they don't match.

Comment: Ok, try now, I edited those loops adding to cells connection to 's' sheet

Comment: It didn't really work. The original code worked at finding values that didn't match when comparing the Unique ID in column B and comparing it to the range the problem is moving the range it is looking it. The range only stays in the first 6 columns but it needs to step as well

Comment: Range You copy or range you are searching?

Comment: Its the range I am searching. After it finishes looping the first 6 columns it moves over to the next 6 columns successfully, but then it starts copying all of the values to the new sheet because it must be comparing it to the old column still.

Comment: Your code is not copying after moving over 6 columns. Your code is copying values row after row if it met condition. I don't get your point.

Comment: My code looks at a cell value and then see's whether it exists in any of the 5 cells to the right in the same row. If that cell value does exist in the range it moves on, if it doesn't it copies that range of 6 cells into a new sheet. 

The problem is after finishing looking in the first block of 6 columns it doesn't start looking for the new cell value which would be 6 columns to the right, it still looks in the first column

Comment: Edited again post.
Set rngSearch = .Range(.Cells(i, j), .Cells(i, j+5)) <--- this is moving in loop, 6 columns to the right every 'j' loop.
Now, have you tried putting my loops into your code?

Comment: Thanks for your help but that didn't work either. I've tried all of your suggestions but it's not exactly helping. I think its the uniqueID variable which needs to move across also

Comment: But
uniqueId = .Cells(i, 2 + j - 1).Value
is also moving. 'j' at first iteration is 1, 2nd 1+6, 3rd 1+6+6.
So uniqueId (column index) --> 2, 8, 14 etc